# How to improve the looks of a table?

Tags: tables, matrices

I want to display measurement outcomes in a table that lets the viewer read off the measurement value of `N` and `$\Theta$`. The picture below shows my first attempt. While this is ok, I would like to make it look nicer. For starters, how do I get the vertical line to go all the way trough? The code is also appended below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\caption{\label{tab2} FMM: profiling of subroutines}
    \begin{tabular}{ll|cccccc}\toprule
    & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{N} \\
    ~ &  & 100    & 200    & 400    & 800    & 1600   & 3200   \\
    \midrule\\
    & 0.1 & 0.0008 & 0.0020 & 0.0056 & 0.0180 & 0.0556 & 0.1708 \\
    & 0.2 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0108 & 0.0300 & 0.0792 \\
   $\Theta$ & 0.4 & 0.0004 & 0.0012 & 0.0028 & 0.0060 & 0.0140 & 0.0344 \\
    & 0.8 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0064 & 0.0148 \\
    & 1.6 & 0.0004 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0028 & 0.0036 & 0.0080 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs just did, is it ok like that?

Comment: Yes, that looks much better :) The rationale is that you want to make it easy for others to help you; you're more likely to get a speedy and satisfactory answer if people don't have to "manually" complete your code in order to compile it, understand what you're trying to achieve and fix what's wrong or missing. So, posting a MWE is a good habit to take on this site.

Comment: I'd remove the \\ after the `\midrule`.

Comment: Also I'd use `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline`.

Comment: `\toprule` etc. requires the `booktabs` package.  The documentation of that package clearly discourages vertical rules at all.  If you wish to ignore that advice, the set your horizontal rules with `\hline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no vertical lines, no centering, friendlier spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,leading}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\leading{16pt}
\caption{\label{tab2} FMM: profiling of subroutines}

    \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
    \cmidrule[0.08em](r){1-2}\cmidrule[0.08em]{3-8}
    & & \textbf{N} \\
     &  & \textbf{100} & \textbf{200} & \textbf{400} & \textbf{800} & \textbf{1600} & \textbf{3200} \\
    \cmidrule[0.08em](r){1-2}\cmidrule[0.08em]{3-8}
    $\Theta$ & 0.1 & 0.0008 & 0.0020 & 0.0056 & 0.0180 & 0.0556 & 0.1708 \\
    & 0.2 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0108 & 0.0300 & 0.0792 \\
    & 0.4 & 0.0004 & 0.0012 & 0.0028 & 0.0060 & 0.0140 & 0.0344 \\
    & 0.8 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0064 & 0.0148 \\
    & 1.6 & 0.0004 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0028 & 0.0036 & 0.0080 \\
        \cmidrule[0.05em](r){1-2}\cmidrule[0.05em]{3-8}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Don't use vertical lines at all:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\caption{\label{tab2} FMM: profiling of subroutines}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}\FL
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\Theta$} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{N} \NN
    \cmidrule(rl){2-7}
         & 100    & 200    & 400    & 800    & 1600   & 3200   \ML
     0.1 & 0.0008 & 0.0020 & 0.0056 & 0.0180 & 0.0556 & 0.1708 \\
     0.2 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0108 & 0.0300 & 0.0792 \\
     0.4 & 0.0004 & 0.0012 & 0.0028 & 0.0060 & 0.0140 & 0.0344 \\
     0.8 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0016 & 0.0036 & 0.0064 & 0.0148 \\
     1.6 & 0.0004 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0028 & 0.0036 & 0.0080 
    \LL
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```